# Decremental reachability in a grid graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

Consider an $n$ by $n$ grid graph. For example, the following.

[image: Grid graph]

You can of course reach the top left corner from the bottom right.  Now consider the graph dynamically with an arbitrary number of edges deleted at each step.

> What is the time complexity of determining whether you can still reach
>   the top left corner from the bottom right after edge deletions?

---

**Further clarification.**

**Queries.** There is exactly one type of query which gives a Boolean output.  That is whether there is a path from the top left corner to the bottom right.

**Updates.** An update can delete an arbitrary number of edges greater than $0$.

**Complexity.**  Each update is followed by a query. The complexity I am interested in is the amortized time over all updates and queries.  The best this could possibly be would be proportional to the number of deleted edges I assume.

---

I found these [lecture notes](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring12/scribe/L20.pdf) which say you can get $O(\log{n})$ time for planar graphs per individual edge deletion ([the Eppstein et al. reference](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/cs97/s08/pdf/eppstein92maintenance.pdf)). However this paper supports many more operations than I need, my graph is a special case of a planar graph and my updates are in batches in a sense.  The most important difference may just be that I am only interested in the decremental version. I haven't found anything specialized for batched, decremental connectivity in a grid graph.

Is there anything simpler than the Eppstein et al. paper for my special case or alternatively faster than $O(\log{n})$ time per edge deletion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Optimal decremental connectivity in planar graphs", by Jakub Łącki, Piotr Sankowski](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.7240) demonstrates an algorithm that uses $O(1)$ amortized time per update and $O(1)$ time per query.

Answer (score 3):

By improving on @emab's idea, you can achieve $\Theta(\alpha(n^2))$ amortized time per deletion and query, where $\alpha$ is the inverse Ackermann function, i.e. almost constant.

- Initialize a [union-find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) with an enry for each square of the grid graph and two entries each for the two pairs of outside faces top+right and bottom+left.
  For an example of $n=3$, the faces $1,2,3,\ldots,9,A,B$ in the diagram below are initialized. Where $A,B$ are the outside faces split by the dashed lines.
  [image]
- When removing an edge call `union()` on the two squares (or the sqare and $A$ or $B$) separated by that edge.
- To check connectivity, call `find()` on the faces $A$ and $B$. If the results differ, return true, else return false.

Comment: Are you assuming that the intersections of the lines in my diagram are the nodes (which is what I intended) or the square spaces?

Comment: @Lembik Yes, that is what I am assuming. The elements in the union-find data structure, however, are the square spaces and not the nodes of the graph.

Comment: @Biliska I agree that your edit makes the post easier to understand. Thanks for that.

Comment: The union-find solution really solves the incremental connectivity problem on not-necessarily-planar graphs, which allows multiple sources / sinks (using a super-source/super-sink). The decremental top-left to bottom-right problem is then reduced to an incremental problem on the dual graph, using the top-most + right-most edges as sources and bottom-most + left-most edges as sinks.

Answer (score -3):

Let's call the top-left node as $s$ and the bottom-right node as $t$.

In the square drawing of this graph, there are four sides (left, right, top, bottom).

Let's call two edges connected, iff they share a square or an endpoint (we can determine if two edges are connected or not in $O(1)$).

As you remove the edges from the graph, you maintain a few lists of those edges.  that are connected, and see if any of them connect one of the four side pairs:

- top to bottom
- top to left
- left to right
- bottom to right

In the following figure, by dashed red lines, I tried to demonstrate a series of edge removals (if the red dashed line crosses an edge, it means that the edge is removed at some point).

(Algorithm is below figure)

[image: Red dashed lines illustrate 4 disconnecting sides (top-bottom, top-left, left-right, bottom-right)]

**Algorithm**

```
Component = []
/* Initialize Hit_Sides by 0 */
Hit_Left = []; Hit_Right = []; Hit_Top = []; Hit_Bottom = []; 
while ( input >> e; /* there is an edge e to be removed */)
    L = L + {e};
    Component[e] = e;
    if (e hits any side s) then
        Hit_s[e] = 1;
    For each e' in L
        if (e' is connected to e)
            Component[e] = Component[e']
        if (e hits any side s)
            Hit_s[Component[e] = 1;
    For each component c in Component
        if (it hits one of the four disconnecting pairs)
            Output << There is no path from s to t
```

BTW, the following explanation is clear and precise. However, if you use geometrical techniques, you may be able to get some logarithmic algorithm out of it.

---

If you maintain a list of edges that are being removed, you can consider the list of connected ones, and see whether they hit any disconnecting sides (top-bottom, top-left, left-right, bottom-right) and answer to that reachability query in $O(1)$.

In the following figure, red lines illustrate the disconnecting sides:

[image: Red dashed lines illustrate 4 disconnecting sides (top-bottom, top-left, left-right, bottom-right)]

Comment: How long are the updates taking in this solution?

Comment: Consider the graph as a grid on a surface. A native method is to check all the previous deleted edges $O(k^2)$ if the number of updates is $k$. I am not sure, but there must be some logarithmic method using geometrical methods and sorting the nodes based  on their ordinates.

Comment: I can't understand this answer or how you get $O(1)$ time.  I don't understand the figure, either.  There are exponentially many possible cuts (red lines); you can't keep track of all of them.

Comment: @D.W. Suppose you have a list of edges that are being removed, then you find the connected ones, and see if they connect any disconnecting side pairs. By "connected ones" I mean having the same square, or endpoint; Once you see if they connect disconnecting pairs, you can determine whether there still is a path from source to sink or not.

Comment: @D.W. We don't keep track of red lines, as we store the connected edges, we just see if they hit any of those four pairs of sides.

Comment: @emab Looking for connected sets of edges does not sound very $O(1)$ to me.

Comment: @FrankW If you look at my first comment, you will see that I mentioned it can be $O(k^2)$ in worst case. The reason that I didn't put this time complexity in the answer was that, there are better algorithms if you sort the edges based on their coordinates.